# Change delimiter checkboxes Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to change the delimiter when getting responses from a Checkbox-question when using Google Forms.

I'm writing the values in a google doc, but I need to be able to split the answers.

Simply replacing all comma's doesn't work, because there are comma's in the answers.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Is it possible to add a small snippet of how the csv is formatted? If I'm not mistaken the answers are encapsulated in quotation marks.

Comment: When I write the string that is returned through the .getresponse command, there are no quotation marks.

Answer (score 8):

Recently had a similar problem, I'll reply in case anyone ends up here (like I did). When exporting Forms responses to a Spreadsheet, the separator is a comma (which is a problem if you have commas in the checkboxes values).

But if instead you use the option "Download responses (.csv)" 9which is right beside the export to spreadsheet button), the resulting CSV has all values quoted, and uses a semicolon for separating within the checkbox column.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me! I will just add that this must be done in Google Forms itself (clicking the dropdown next to "View in Sheets"). When I tried going to the Google Sheets version of the data, then File > Download > .csv from within Sheets, that version does *not* have semicolon delimiters for values within the checkbox column.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is no way to change the delimiter: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/h0fopNaKqzM

You may want to add a dot / double spaces to the end of each box's value, so that you can separate using that.

Let me know if you need another solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the selected choices to appear in separate, designated columns for counting the number of responses that have each choice selected, you can try the method using a combination of IF(), ISERR() and SEARCH() as shown in this video: https://youtu.be/mySZ_eZNmtE. This way it doesn't matter if you've used commas in the choice labels. Only problem is that you'll need to manually add the responses that come under "Other", if that option is given.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To split the answers, you can use comma space (, )

So, you can use comma only without space in your answers