# Showing Checkbox value as Bullet points with delimiter involved

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've a scenario, I am actually using the script to create a document/pdf when user submits the form, pretty normal in apps script but I've a situation where I've some checkbox values and I want to show them as Buller points in Google Doc, so normally when someone submits the form with multiple selection in checkbox it stores them in Sheet separating them using comma(,), so I decided to split the value by comma and then i'll have all choices in an array,
but situation is that some checkbox values itself have "," for example "Falls, car accidents, or any other accidents/injuries in past 3 months" so this is one of the value in checkbox of google form, so I when i am splitting it using delimiter comma(",") it is splitting comma belong to actual values too, I hope it make sense, can some one help me to resolve this situation so I can get all values in bullet points in google doc without impacting comma thing.

here is the part of code I am using:-

```
function createPDF_(row,sheet,response)
{
   const head = sheet.getRange('1:1').getValues().flat()

   const posIncrement =  head.indexOf('[Form Publisher] Increment')
   const pos_pdfURL  =  head.indexOf('Response PDF URL')


   const PAST_MHistory = response[`Past Medical History (Type 'NONE' below if there is no significant medical history)`][0]
   const PAST_SURGICAL = response[`Past Surgical History (Type 'NONE' below if there is no significant surgical history)`][0]
   const MEDICATION_LIST = response[`Please list all medications you are currently taking (Type 'NONE' below if you are not taking medications)`][0] 
   const PROBLEM_LEN = response['How long have you been dealing with this problem?'][0] 
   const SEEN_TYPE = response['Do you prefer to be seen in person or have virtual (online) sessions?'][0] 
   const CONSENT = response[`Please click to download and read our "Attendance Policy, Privacy Policy, Financial Policy and Consent to Treat and click an answer below if you AGREE or DISAGREE to the policies as written here:`][0] 
   
   const today = new Date()
   const todays_Date_f = Utilities.formatDate(today,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM dd yyyy") 
   const timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(today,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
   const todaydate = Utilities.formatDate(today,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy")
   const targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderID)
   const template = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID)
   
   const docFile = template.makeCopy(`Intake Form_${LAST_NAME}_${FIRST_NAME}`,targetFolder)
   const doc = DocumentApp.openById(docFile.getId())
   const body = doc.getBody()  
   const header = doc.getHeader()
   /**  Logics to replace template literals to actual values */
   body.replaceText('<<Past Medical History>>',PAST_MHistory)
   body.replaceText('<<Past Surgical History>>',PAST_SURGICAL)
   body.replaceText('<<List of Medication>>',MEDICATION_LIST)
   body.replaceText('<<Problem Duration>>',PROBLEM_LEN)
   body.replaceText('<<Session Type>>',SEEN_TYPE)
   body.replaceText('<<Consent>>',CONSENT)
   doc.saveAndClose()
   
   var pdfBlob = doc.getAs('application/pdf');
   var pdfFile = targetFolder.createFile(pdfBlob);
   sheet.getRange(row,posIncrement+1).setValue(row+5)
   sheet.getRange(row,pos_pdfURL+1).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl())
   docFile.setTrashed(true)

}
```

So currently it is updating like this :-

[image]

But i am trying to show them like this :-

[image]

If there is other way to do that, please guide me, because I am kind of stuck with it now.

Comment: Related question: [Change delimiter checkboxes Google Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49999593/1330560) - several ideas here.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use commas in the options I'd suggest that you use a common word or key that you could use to split the response instead.

For example for the question `What limitations are you experiencing?` you could use `Limited with` as a separator to get an array of the data that you'll use:

```
- basic daily activities around the home.
- work or community activities.
- sport, fitness or recreational activities.
```